# <a href=".."> doesn't work at first click but works at second click in FF, in IE works fine

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have

```
<td class="TableContent">
    <bean:message key="image.arrow.link" />
    <a href="#Link"><bean:message  key="text.linkinfo"/></a><br>
</td>
```

and

```
<a name="Link"><bean:message key="text.linkinfo"/></a>
```

When I first click on the link in FF the page just reloads and when clicking again after this it goes to where it should.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: since we're dealing with a browser itssue, it would be more helpful to see the finished HTML code as the browser sees it, rather than those bean tags.

Comment: Please post only the html output.

Comment: `href` attribute must point to `id` attribute of target (link) element, not a `name` attribute. As result: `<a id="Link"><bean:message key="text.linkinfo"/></a>`

Comment: @Andrew: What? I think you've misunderstood what anchor tags are, and confused HTML for Javascript.

Comment: @Mike: Please produce a testcase that demonstrates the issue, and tell us which browser versions are affected and which are not.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: _`href` This is the single required attribute for anchors defining a hypertext source link. It indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL fragment, that is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (**an ID**) within the current document._

Comment: @Andrew: That doesn't mean an `id` attribute any more than it means the photo ID in my wallet. Link targets have been [specified in `name` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1) for decades. \[ **edit:** that w3 link says that _either_ is OK, which is news to me. Certainly, though, `name` is not invalid.\]

Comment: @Andrew: BTW where was that quote from?

Comment: The html output is:          

     <td class="TableContent">
                    <img src="images/arrowIconLink.gif" border="0"><a href="#Link">Link</a><br/>
                  </td>  
        
    
       <a name="Link">Link</a>

I also tried  `<a id="Link">Link</a>` and still the same issue.

Thank you for you answers!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3  This is fact: `name` attribute is used as target only for anchors ( `A` tags), but for all others tags `name` is not works. This behaviour is valid for FF and Chrome. As result: is best to use `id` attribute.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: `BTW where was that quote from?` MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/A

Comment: @Mike: Can you post full HTML? Can you temporary change `<a id="Link">Link</a>` to `<H1 id="TempLink">Link</H1>` and `<a href="#Link"><bean:message  key="text.linkinfo"/></a>` to `<a href="#TempLink">Go to TempLink</a>`. Maybe you have more than one element with same `id`|`name` attribute value?

Comment: @Andrew: `name attribute is used as target only for anchors ( A tags) but for all others tags name is not works`. We are talking about anchor tags. The OP is using an anchor tag. So your initial comment `href attribute must point to id attribute of target (link) element, not a name attribute` is incorrect. This entire line of discussion is without purpose!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Do You have any guarantee, that @Mike have only one _target_ on page?, or that @Mike do not have nonunique _target_ `name`s or `id`s? Reloading of page occurs when valid `id`|`name` is not found on page! _this is all what I want to say. only practice. no more comments_

Comment: @Andrew: No, and I wasn't talking about that aspect at all. I feel like you haven't really been reading my comments properly, so I'm not going to post any more.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the html page, it's too big. I tried that suggestion with H and the same thing is happening. The names for <a are unique on my page. The reloading is happening in IE also but there the page is loaded at the wanted point.

Comment: @Mike Uhm, maybe I'm wrong but the declaration of your anchor is wrong. An anchor is a hidden element and has no link text. It is just a bookmark within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with using base tag and relative href in my case. I fixed the problem on all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari) using the entire link address.